# jQuery SlideOut Function from Right to Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to slideout function from rightside in jQuery, by changing the code for "From Left to Right" but it's not functioning correctly... Can u please give me the right direction to modify...

http://jsfiddle.net/egUHv/

Presently I am using this code...

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav').stop().animate({'marginRight':'-100px'},1000);

    function toggleDivs() {
       var $inner = $("#nav");
       if ($inner.position().right == "-100px") {
           $inner.animate({right: 0});
           $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="open" />')
       }
       else {
           $inner.animate({right: "100px"}); 
           $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="close" />')
       }
    }
    $(".nav-btn").bind("click", function(){
        toggleDivs();
    });

});
```

Comment: Create a sample on JsFiddle

Answer (score 11):

just see this link it will be useful http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

or use this

```
$("div").click(function () {
          $(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Answer (score 5):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/egUHv/5/

```
$(function() {
$('#nav').stop().animate({'margin-right':'-100px'},1000);

function toggleDivs() {
var $inner = $("#nav");
if ($inner.css("margin-right") == "-100px") {
    $inner.animate({'margin-right': '0'});
    $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="open" />')
}
else {
    $inner.animate({'margin-right': "-100px"}); 
    $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="close" />')
}
}
$(".nav-btn").bind("click", function(){
    toggleDivs();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution:

```
$(function() {
  $('#div').ToggleSlide();
});

$.fn.ToggleSlide = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');

        if(parseInt($(this).css('right')) < 0) {
            $(this).animate({ 'right' : '-100px' }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).css('position', 'relative');
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).animate({ 'right' : '0px' }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).css('position', 'relative');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What we do here: 
On function call we set the item's position to 'absolute' so we can animate it easy.
We check if the item has negative 'right' (is already moved to the right), if true we animate back to 0 (right-to-left motion), else we animate to '-right'  (left-to-right motion). Once the animation is completed, we set the item's position to 'relative' so we can use it's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

We have now the [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

> animate.css is a bunch of cool, fun, and cross-browser animations for you to use in your projects. Great for emphasis, home pages, sliders, and general just-add-water-awesomeness.

You can call animate effects from jquery. Clean and effective